# Kafka-python How to consume json message

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I am a fairly new in Python and starting with Kafka. I have a requirement where I need to send and consume json messages. For this I am using [kafka-python](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/usage.html) to communicate with Kafka.

```
#Producer.py
from kafka import KafkaProducer
import json
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092',value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode('utf-8'))
producer.send('offering_new', {"dataObjectID": "test1"})

#Consumer.py
import json
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092',auto_offset_reset='earliest', value_deserializer=lambda m: json.loads(m.decode('utf-8')))
consumer.subscribe(['offering_new'])
for message in consumer :
    print(message)
```

However I'm getting the following exception on consumer :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/paras/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kafka/consumer/group.py", line 1111, in __next__
    return next(self._iterator)
  File "/home/paras/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kafka/consumer/group.py", line 1082, in _message_generator
    for msg in self._fetcher:
  File "/home/paras/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kafka/consumer/fetcher.py", line 482, in __next__
    return next(self._iterator)
  File "/home/paras/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kafka/consumer/fetcher.py", line 388, in _message_generator
    self._next_partition_records = self._parse_fetched_data(completion)
  File "/home/paras/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kafka/consumer/fetcher.py", line 799, in _parse_fetched_data
    unpacked = list(self._unpack_message_set(tp, records))
  File "/home/paras/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kafka/consumer/fetcher.py", line 458, in _unpack_message_set
    tp.topic, record.value)
  File "/home/paras/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kafka/consumer/fetcher.py", line 492, in _deserialize
    return f(bytes_)
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I am running the above code in Python Shell. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: did you check from console first if the messages written are valid json?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With `auto_offset_reset='earliest'` you have configured your consumer to read all messages in the topic. A JSON decoding error suggests that some message that was previously produced to the topic is not actually in JSON format.

Some solutions:

(1) consume from the tail of the topic instead: `auto_offset_reset='latest'`

(2) start a new topic: `consumer.subscribe(['offering_new_too'])`

(3) use a more comprehensive deserializer:

```
def forgiving_json_deserializer(v):
    return if v is None
    try:
        return json.loads(v.decode('utf-8'))
    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
        log.exception('Unable to decode: %s', v)
        return None

KafkaConsumer(value_deserializer=forgiving_json_deserializer, ...)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was getting same error, `changing auto_offset_reset='latest'` resolved my issue. Thanks a lot

Comment: will the consumer keep continue to process other messages in case the `forgiving_json_deserializer` returns  `None`. any reference for this?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have follow below process

```
pip install kafka-python
```

import below lib in python script

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
from json import loads
```

create kafka consumer object like below

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    'spring_test',
     bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
     auto_offset_reset='earliest',
     enable_auto_commit=True,
     group_id='my-group',
     value_deserializer=lambda x: loads(x.decode('utf-8')));
```

print all messages

```
for message in consumer:
    message = message.value;
    print('{}'.format(message))
```

Hope this will help as well

Comment: To continually consume, would you run this in a `while True` loop. And also how would you set it so that you only carry on from the last message that you read, instead of going through all of them again?

Comment: you are not handling the case where the message is not json decodable.